# MKL function parameters incompatible on Linux while compatible on Windows Visual Studio

Tags: c++, linux, intel-mkl

I am wrting an algebra library for a large project using MKL.

The algebra library is working rightly on Linux now, i am now trying to make it work on Linux using CMake for cross-platform compiling.

Part of my CMakeLists.txt to link MKL is like this:

```
#find MKL on Linux
find_package(MKL REQUIRED)
message(STATUS "${MKL_IMPORTED_TARGETS}")
if(MKL_FOUND)
    message(STATUS "MKL IS FOUND ON LINUX")
    message(STATUS "MKL_ROOT IS ${MKL_ROOT}")
    include_directories(${MKL_ROOT}/include)
    target_link_libraries(algebra_test_linux PRIVATE MKL::mkl_intel_ilp64 MKL::mkl_intel_thread MKL::mkl_core MKL::MKL)
else()
    message(WARNING "MKL libs not found")
endif(MKL_FOUND)
```

I think i have linked this programm to MKL because i run this code sample perfectly:

```
#include "mkl_test_linux.h"

#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<mkl.h>
int main()
{
    float* A, * B;//declare two vectors
    int a = 1, b = 1;//
    int n = 5;
    A = (float*)mkl_malloc(n * 1 * sizeof(float), 64);
    B = (float*)mkl_malloc(n * 1 * sizeof(float), 64);
    printf("The 1st vector is ");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        A[i] = i;
        printf("%2.0f", A[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("The 2st vector is ");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        B[i] = i + 1;
        printf("%2.0f", B[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    //计算a*A+b*B
    cblas_saxpby(n, a, A, 1, b, B, 1);
    printf("The a*A+b*B is ");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%2.0f", B[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    mkl_free(A);
    mkl_free(B);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

However, my algebra_test on Linux come across many warnings like this :

```
cannot convert 'int*' to 'long long int*'
cannot convert 'int*' to 'long long int*'
cannot convert 'int*' to 'const long long int*'
cannot convert 'int*' to 'const long long int*'
```

I made some research telling me that this is caused by argument incompatible, but this is fine when i am using it on Windows.

I wonder how to fix this problem, thank you everyone.

Comment: Do you use the same warning flags/levels on Linux on Windows? It could well be that you get the same warnings on Windows if you crank up the warning level. Another reason for this could be that you are building 32bit binaries in one and 64bit binaries in the other case. It probably is a good idea to look at the function definitions in the mkl header file.

Comment: I suspect you are running into the issue that on x86_64 Windows ``int`` and ``long`` are both 32bit, but on Linux ``int`` is 32bit and ``long`` is 64bit. (``long long`` is 64bit on both.) For values this is not much of an issue, but the error messages you posted suggests there are pointers involved. Unfortunately I don't see any pointers to integers in your code, so I can't tell you what you'd need to change to make it work... Could you post a more complete example and also more specific error messages that include which files they occur in?

Comment: Looks like you've raised a thread https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-oneAPI-Math-Kernel-Library/MKL-function-parameters-incompatible-on-Linux-while-compatible/m-p/1499887#M3001 in Intel Communities.  We assume that your issue is resolved here.